# how can load images from plist in to UITableView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, uiimageview

I have stored the videos and the thumbnail images of the videos in Documents folder. And I have given the path in plist. In plist I took an array and I added directories to the array.
And in the dictionary I stored the image path

```
/Users/srikanth/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/9E6E8B22-C946-4442-9209-75BB0E924434/Documents/image1
```

for key imagePath.

for video

```
/Users/srikanth/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/9E6E8B22-C946-4442-9209-75BB0E924434/Documents/video1.mp4
```

for key filePath.

I used  following code but it is not working. I am trying only for images. I need the images to be loaded in the table in each cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
        UIImageView *image2;
        image2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 80.0f, 80.0f);
        image2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

    }
    NSDictionary *dictOfplist = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *path = [dictOfplist objectForKey:@"imagePath"];
    NSLog("path: %@", path);
    return cell;
}  

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Library";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(close:)];

    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"details" ofType:@"plist"];
    contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[contentArray count]];

    for(dCount = 0; dCount < [contentArray count]; dCount++)
        [cells addObject:[contentArray objectAtIndex:dCount]];
}
```

I got the path of the images are from the plist.
 But, how can I extract the image from the path.
The output od NSLog: is

```
path: /Users/srikanth/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/9E6E8B22-C946-4442-9209-75BB0E924434/Documents/snook.jpg
```

How can I get the image from it and store in cell.imageView.image ?
How can I make this work. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems in your code:

- When you are creating the UITableViewCell instance, you create an UIImageView `image2` that is not assigned and therefore leaks memory. Is not normal ?
- You do not need to get a reference to the UIImageView of the cell by tag. An UITableViewCell already has an UIImageView and its image can be set with the `cell.imageView.image` property.

Where are you loading the UIImage ? You say you are storing the image path, but there is no code for loading image from this path.

Comment: I thought that passing key value of the dictionary in plist gives the path. My mistake. I stored the path in the dictionary in plist for key value imagePath. How can we get the path from the plist in to our code? I will check my code and correct it.

Thank You.

Comment: I got the path of the image. but how to get the image from it ?
Th path is
path: /Users/srikanth/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/9E6E8B22-C946-4442-9209-75BB0E924434/Documents/snook.jpg
How to show the image snook.jpg from the path in cell ?

Comment: Use the "imageWithContentsOfFile:" method of UIImage:

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: I did it but it is not working. It is not showing images in the cell.
When I debugged, img is showing as 0*0. Any suggestions please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Thank You very much Laurent sir. I got the correct solution finally. And I messed all my time without clear knowledge of what I need and what I should do. Now, I kept the images in the Documents folder and the file name in plist. I accessed it with this file name. I used UIImage property you suggested me. Now I got the images in my table cell.
Thank You.